# Is it possible to wait until other thread processes input messages posted to it?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winapi

I want to simulate user input to other window reliably. I use `SendInput` for this, but then I need to wait until target app handles the input before sending more. As far as I know, `SendInput`, despite its name, really posts messages to the queue and does not wait until they're processed.

My try is based on the idea to wait until message queue is empty at least once. As I can't check other's thread message queue directly (at least I don't know a way to do so), I'm using `AttachThreadInput` to attach target thread's queue to this thread's one and then `PeekMessage` to check.

In order to check the function I use small app with one window and a button. When button is clicked I call `Thread.Sleep(15000)` effectively stopping message processing, thus ensuring that for the next 15s message queue can't be empty.

Code is here:

```
    public static void WaitForWindowInputIdle(IntPtr hwnd)
    {
        var currentThreadId = GetCurrentThreadId();
        var targetThreadId = GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, IntPtr.Zero);

        Func<bool> checkIfMessageQueueIsEmpty = () =>
        {
            bool queueEmpty;
            bool threadsAttached = false;

            try
            {
                threadsAttached = AttachThreadInput(targetThreadId, currentThreadId, true);

                if (threadsAttached) 
                {
                    NativeMessage nm;
                    queueEmpty = !PeekMessage(out nm, hwnd, 0, 0, RemoveMsg.PM_NOREMOVE | RemoveMsg.PM_NOYIELD);
                }
                else
                    throw new ThreadStateException("AttachThreadInput failed.");
            }
            finally
            {
                if (threadsAttached)
                    AttachThreadInput(targetThreadId, currentThreadId, false);
            }
            return queueEmpty;
        };

        var timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(15000);
        var retryInterval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500);
        var start = DateTime.Now;
        while (DateTime.Now - start < timeout)
        {
            if (checkIfMessageQueueIsEmpty()) return;
            Thread.Sleep(retryInterval);
        }
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool PeekMessage(out NativeMessage lpMsg,
                                   IntPtr hWnd,
                                   uint wMsgFilterMin,
                                   uint wMsgFilterMax,
                                   RemoveMsg wRemoveMsg);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct NativeMessage
    {
        public IntPtr handle;
        public uint msg;
        public IntPtr wParam;
        public IntPtr lParam;
        public uint time;
        public System.Drawing.Point p;
    }

    [Flags]
    private enum RemoveMsg : uint
    {
        PM_NOREMOVE = 0x0000,
        PM_REMOVE = 0x0001,
        PM_NOYIELD = 0x0002,
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool AttachThreadInput(uint idAttach, uint idAttachTo, bool fAttach);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr processId);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern uint GetCurrentThreadId();
```

Now, it is not working for some reason. It always returns that the message queue is empty. Does someone know what I'm doing wrong, or maybe some other way to achieve what I need?

**EDIT:** About why I need to wait in the first place.
If other actions are simulated immediately without pause, I encounter situations when text is entered only partially. E.g. I simulated "abcdefgh" via SendInput when focus is at some text box, and right after that - some mouse click. What I get is "abcde" typed and click after that. If I put Thread.Sleep(100) after SendInput - the problem is not reproducible on my machine, but rarely reproducible on VM with low hardware. So I need more reliable way to wait correct amount of time.

My speculation of what might be going on is related to [`TranslateMessage` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644955%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> Translates virtual-key messages into character messages. The character messages are posted to the calling thread's message queue, to be read the next time the thread calls the GetMessage or PeekMessage function.

So, I call `SendInput` for "abcdefgh" - bunch of input messages posted to the thread queue. Then it starts to process those messages in FIFO order, translating "abcde", and posting messages for each char to queue's tail. Then mouse click is simulated and posted after character messages for "abcde". Then translating finishes, but translated messages for "fgh" happens *after* the mouse click. And finally app sees "abcde", then click, then "fgh" - obviously going to some wrong place...

Comment: PeekMessage() returning FALSE just means that the message queue is empty.  It doesn't mean that the app is responsive.  You would have to call PostMessage() to ensure it isn't empty.  Calling PeekMessage() on a window owned by another process is troublesome, I don't think that can work. The reason that a message queue exists is so you don't have to do this :)

Comment: @HansPassant It seems to me after another round of googling that notion of Input Queue is different from Message Queue hence attaching input queues together won't get me messages targeted to other window anyway (as you've said), only syncronizes input queues together... But that brings me another idea: create hidden window in current process (just to receive messages) and post some input to it under attached input queues - since queues are synch'ed - I should not receive my message until other window's input is handled. Does this have a chance to work, in your opinion?

Comment: You should specify exactly the "I need to wait until target app handles the input before sending more". That may involves something else that empty message queues.

Comment: @manuell emptying message queue necessarily involves processing all of the input queue messages, so it is stronger condition. What I really need is to ensure that everything posted to the queue by `SendInput` call is handled before going further.

Comment: I understood that, and that was in your question. Question is: why?

Comment: @manuell if other actions are simulated immediately without pause, I encounter situations when text is entered only partially. E.g. I simulated "abcdefgh" via `SendInput` when focus is at some text box, and right after that - some mouse click. What I get is "abcde" typed and click after that. If I put `Thread.Sleep(100)` after `SendInput` - the problem is not reproducible on my machine, but rarely reproducible on VM with low hardware. So I need more reliable way to wait correct amount of time.

Comment: PeekMessage returns only messages for your thread.

Comment: Solution is to hook messages (posted and sent) and check what happens (WM_keyboard, WM_mouse, WM_SETFOCUS, ...). You'll need some basic IPC, maybe.

Comment: @RaymondChen is it possible to add message to input queue of current thread and synchronize it with target thread's input queue with `AttachThreadInput`, so that `GetMessage` called for current thread's window blocks until all prior messages sent to target thread's input queue are handled?

Comment: Attaching input queues between threads that don't know about each other is not a great idea. What if the thread you attached to sends you input and waits for you?

Comment: @RaymondChen I was going to attach another thread to mine and I know that my thread won't send any input, because the only window it owns is hidden. And in general, in my situation one app is test automation driver and another is app being tested. Hence they know about each other. Moreover, test driver knows precisely what it is trying to test/automate. It seems like a more friendly situation then zero-knowledge-about-each-other.

Comment: If the threads know about each other, then have the other thread signal you when it finishes processing input.

Comment: @RaymondChen to be honest, I don't know a way to do this in WPF. Plus, it sounds somewhat strange to write some risky low-level things in production code just to make tests more stable. What are the shortcomings of merging input queues in my case? Except that I still can't make it work, of course :)

Comment: Merged input queues doesn't really help you because you cannot peek messages for another thread. You could install a WH_CALLWNDPROCRET hook - that notifies you after each message processing completes.

Comment: @RaymondChen I came to that understanding already, so the code in question is incorrect. Now I'm thinking about [this](https://gist.github.com/ivan-danilov/8369910) - I'm putting message to my own thread, but the problem is that `PostMessage` puts message to the message queue, not input queue hence it is handled before hardware input queue as stated in `GetMessage` documentation. Is there any way to add item to input queue of specific thread? If not - it seems hooks are the only way.

Comment: And with hooks I don't see how I can tell that all input that I've simulated is handled - any number of input events may come before simulated ones, plus I can't even say if there's any still left in the queue because `GetQueueStatus` works for current thread only...

Comment: Have you envisaged to use UI Automation for what you ultimately want to achieve (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_UI_Automation)?

Comment: You can't show that all processing is complete just by looking at messages because a control might do part of the work immediately and then do some more work asynchronously. You need to have cooperation from the control to know for sure when it has finished processing. UI Automation is handy because controls typically fire UI automation events at the end of their processing.

Comment: @RaymondChen I'm working with White framework built on top of UIA. It tries to use 'real' mouse & kbd actions if it can, and switches to UIA patters otherwise. So, I know that it is TextBox control and how it should respond to typing some chars. I get the result value from UIA directly to validate results.

Comment: @SimonMourier yes, I'm aware of UIA and actively using it. See prev comment for Raymond Chen.

Comment: You can wait for the UIA "content changed" notification to tell you that the control has probably finished updating its content.

Comment: @RaymondChen Ah. Thanks, I will try that way. Don't know why I haven't thought about UIA notifications before :)

Comment: @RaymondChen it is still not the ideal solution because in some cases (e.g. textbox's maximum length is reached) content won't change as a result. But the objection that in general I can't tell by messages that processing is finished by control - is valid... Thanks for your time. Could you make your comments to some answer, so I can assign bounty to you?

Comment: I do not need bounty. You may create your own answer with a summary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a common need in UI Automation.  It is in fact implemented in .NET by the [WindowPattern.WaitForInputIdle() method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.windowpattern.waitforinputidle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

You'd be well-off using the System.Windows.Automation namespace to implement this.  The method is however easy to implement yourself.  You can have a look-see from the Reference Source or a decompiler.  It surprised me a bit how they did it, it looks solid however.  Instead of trying to guess if the message queue is empty, it just looks at the state of the UI thread that owns the window.  If it is blocked and it isn't waiting for an internal system operation then you have a very strong signal that the thread is waiting for Windows to deliver the next message.  I wrote it like this:

```
using namespace System.Diagnostics;
...
    public static bool WaitForInputIdle(IntPtr hWnd, int timeout = 0) {
        int pid;
        int tid = GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, out pid);
        if (tid == 0) throw new ArgumentException("Window not found");
        var tick = Environment.TickCount;
        do {
            if (IsThreadIdle(pid, tid)) return true;
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(15);
        }  while (timeout > 0 && Environment.TickCount - tick < timeout);
        return false;
    }

    private static bool IsThreadIdle(int pid, int tid) {
        Process prc = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessById(pid);
        var thr = prc.Threads.Cast<ProcessThread>().First((t) => tid == t.Id);
        return thr.ThreadState == ThreadState.Wait &&
               thr.WaitReason == ThreadWaitReason.UserRequest;
    }

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("User32.dll")]
    private static extern int GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out int pid);
```

Call WaitForInputIdle() in your code before calling SendInput().  The window handle you must pass is pretty flexible, *any* window handle will do as long as it is owned by the UI thread of the process.  The Process.MainWindowHandle is already a very good candidate.  Beware that the method will throw an exception if the process terminates.

Comment: It is definitely an interesting idea, but assumption of "properly implemented as a UI thread that doesn't block for any reason other than obtaining the next message" is too strict. Actually even my app-in-question has legacy code that violates the assumption. +1 nevertheless :)

Comment: Meh, that's a very hard rule in GUI programming.  A .NET program can't block the UI thread, using *lock* or calling WaitHandle.WaitOne() will not actually block the thread.  The CLR will pump a message loop inside the wait to honor the STA contract.

Comment: That's very interesting, I didn't know, thanks. I assume when UI thread still goes to wait state other than waiting for message to arrive - UI becomes 'Not responding', right?

Comment: Then it is probably the closest to what I wanted. I'll employ it to my code, run a bunch of tests and reply here afterwards.

Comment: Thanks, it is really solid. Marked as an answer, bounty will be eligible in 20 hours.

Comment: Interesting.  That's subtly different than the native WinAPI call WaitForInputIdle, which is only good once at application startup.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687022.aspx

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy: There's another subtle difference: [WaitForInputIdle waits for any thread, which might not be the thread you care about](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/03/26/9985422.aspx).