# SetWindowPos/ShowWindow with a timeout

Tags: c, windows, multithreading, winapi

I'm using the `SetWindowPos` function for an automation task to show a window. I know that there are two ways that Windows provides to do this:

- Synchronously: `SetWindowPos` or `ShowWindow`.
- Asynchronously: `SetWindowPos` with `SWP_ASYNCWINDOWPOS` or `ShowWindowAsync`.

Now, I'd like to get the best of both worlds: I want to be able to show the window synchronously, because I'd like it to be done when the function returns. **But** I don't want the call to hang my process - if it takes too long, I want to be able to abort the call.

Now, while looking for an answer, the only thing I could come up with is using a separate thread and using `SendMessageTimeout`, but even then, if the thread hangs, there's not much I can do to end it except of `TerminateProcess`, which is not a clean solution.

I also have seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21028326/is-it-possible-to-wait-until-other-thread-processes-input-messages-posted-to-it), but as far as I understand, it has no alternative for native WinAPI.

Comment: Are you issuing the command from a thread that has a different input queue than the one that owns the window?

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy yes, and a different process. The target is another program I have no control over.

Comment: UI Automation (mentioned in the other answer you linked to) exists for native WinAPI programs.  It's just a little harder to use because you don't get all the runtime help in managing the COM objects.  But if you're trying to drive another application (especially one you didn't write), UI Automation is generally the best way to go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer in the question you linked to simply loops until either the desired condition occurs or the timeout expires. It uses `Sleep()` every iteration to avoid hogging the processor. So a version for WinAPI can be written quite simply, as follows:

```
bool ShowWindowAndWait(HWND hWnd, DWORD dwTimeout) {
    if (IsWindowVisible(hWnd)) return true;
    if (!ShowWindowAsync(hWnd, SW_SHOW)) return false;
    DWORD dwTick = GetTickCount();
    do {
        if (IsWindowVisible(hWnd)) return true;
        Sleep(15);
    } while (dwTimeout != 0 && GetTickCount() - dwTick < dwTimeout);
    return false;
}
```

Unfortunately I think this is the best you're going to get. `SendMessageTimeout` can't actually be used for this purpose because (as far as I know anyway) there's no actual message you could send with it that would cause the target window to be shown. `ShowWindowAsync` and `SWP_ASYNCWINDOWPOS` both work by scheduling internal window events, and this API isn't publicly exposed.

Comment: Oh, SWP_ASYNCWINDOWPOS exists!! Thanks!!